# Oracle form unable to read correct item value in second session,after Update and commit of Item value in first session

Tags: oracleforms

I’m working with Oracle11g Form Builder tool. On my form I’ve multiple columns of table out of which three are ‘UPDATE_BY’, ‘DDU_SAVE’ and ‘FLAG’, and one button ‘IT Verify’.

---

When User enters a row along with other columns, DDU_SAVE is set to ‘Y’; Flag is set to ‘N’ and UPDATE_BY captures User-Id of the person doing data entry

---

The button is visible only to person logging with Admin Rights (say Admin). I need based on the Value of DDU_SAVE=’Y’ and FLAG=’N’, Admin can update row of another table when ‘IT Verify’ button is pressed. But I can see that only when UPDATE_BY is Admin, Updating in another table is possible else not.
I want to mention here that there is no other trigger is written with this code.
I need help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you provide some code? When do you set button visibility?

Comment: Button is at BLock1(DB Block) At WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED<BR>  Begin
   Declare
   v_DDU_AN varchar2(2);
   v_FLAG_AN varchar2(2);
   Begin
    select DDU_VAL,FLAG into v_DDU_AN,v_FLAG_AN from PAY_TM0_ANINCR Where emp_code=:PAY_TM0_ANINCR.emp_code and ENTRY='C';
If v_DDU_AN ='Y' and v_FLAG_AN='N' then 
update pay_tm_emp set scale_code=:PAY_TM0_ANINCR.SCALE_CODE,basic=:PAY_TM0_ANINCR.basic where emp_code=:PAY_TM0_ANINCR.emp_code;
end if;
   
  END;

Comment: Button visibility is set at WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE Code is -*select grp_id into v_usr_grp from scs_tm0_usrmas where usr_id =NVL(:global.g_login_id,'X');
   IF v_usr_grp = 2014 THEN 
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('PAY_TM0_EMPPERDET.IT_VALID',VISIBLE,PROPERTY_TRUE); 
   ELSE
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('PAY_TM0_EMPPERDET.IT_VALID',VISIBLE,PROPERTY_FALSE); 
   END IF;*

Answer (score 0):

Your WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger seems to be ok. This is good way to mofify form behavior according to user access rights.

Problem is in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger. Place UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE commands ONLY into transactional triggers. This is the only way how to achieve reliable transaction.

In your WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger is missing COMMIT command. Other sessions cannot see the update until user presses KEY-COMMIT.

Comment: I’ve one other button which is visible to every user and after saving record User has to Press it which in turn sets  the value of DDU_VAL=’Y and FLAG=’N’, and commit it. After that at DB we can find DDU_VAL=’Y, FLAG=’N’
Later on In the Next session Admin has to login and need to run Update statement on another table as described above.

Comment: Ok, I understand (I hope :) ). Problem is, that you update a record in pay_tm_emp  table but you never insert it. When update does not find record, it does not insert new one! Am I right? If so, I will update the answer. You have to add POST-UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Sir, I've row in PAY_TM_EMP,whenever entry of increment is saved in PAY_TM_ANINCR table Admin need to Update BASIC and GRADE PAY of same employee under PAY_TM_EMP,from data found in PAY_TM_ANINCR

Comment: Then check data in database after user presses button and commits. You will see if problem is in first step (user presses button) or second (admin presses button)

Comment: I had checked that at DB,after user presses button fields are set to desirable values. Only Problem is when logging with Admin ,form shows as if can not read value at DB. All Items' Database Item Property is set to 'YES'.